# SQL Grouping by offset date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Let's say I have a table with names, daily gains, and dates

```
GainTable

NAME     GAIN     DATE
JOHN     10      01/01/2014
ISABEL   20      01/02/2014
VASILIY  10      01/01/2014
```

Let's say that each person has gain for everyday.

I want to find out monthly amount of gains for each person got

I did it like this.

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(GAIN), MONTH(DATE)
FROM GainTable
group by Name, YEAR(DATE), MONTH(DATE)
```

Now, my task is to group by Month, like before, but starting from the 2nd day of the month, and finishing on the 1st day of next month (ex. August group would start August 2- Sept 1).
How can I do that? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks AHiggins, Aquillo! Learning something everyday.

Comment: You're welcome!  Can I suggest that, to aid future people looking for the same thing, you change your question's title to be "SQL Grouping by offset date range" or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just subtracting a single date from your 'real' one and grouping by that month (and year):

```
SELECT NAME,YEAR(DATEADD(D, -1, DATE)), MONTH(DATEADD(D, -1, DATE)), SUM(GAIN) Gain_Total
FROM GainTable
GROUP BY Name, YEAR(DATEADD(D, -1, DATE)), MONTH(DATEADD(D, -1, DATE))
```